# php $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] not working correctly on windows 7

Tags: php, apache, windows-7

I have a problem and this only happens on my PC (windows 7 64bits), if I echo the following:

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

I get :   `::1`

same thing if i insert in database.

????

Comment: how are you connecting the PHP server? localhost? are you working on the same server as well? or are you connecting to a Remote Host?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`::1` is equivalent to `127.0.0.1` in IPv6. That address is equal to `localhost`, as well, if your hosts file was not altered.

Comment: ah! ok. so everything's fine?

Comment: If you are on the same computer as the PHP module, it will return the loopback address in IPv4 or IPv6, depending on your system settings.

Answer (score 1):

Easily ::1 is indeed the result of localhost, but if u use this if else u could fake your localhost:

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

```
                if($ip == '::1')
                    {
                        echo '127.0.0.1';
                    }
                else
                    {
                        echo $ip;
                    }
```